# OLE DB command in visual C# for splitting serial data

Tags: c#, split, serial-port, oledb

I have a problem on how to split data from serial port and then save it to access database to its designated column. i found an example written in VB.net but i cannot find an example code written in c#. the serial data will be like this:

,230,302

,230,302

and continuously.

This is what i have written so far:

```
void sp_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        string[] data = _serialPort.ReadExisting().Split(',');
        OleDbConnection connect = new OleDbConnection();
        connect.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\xp\Desktop\HydroDatabase.accdb";
        connect.Open();
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
        command.CommandText = "INSERT Into HydroLog(WaterFlow,TurbineRPM) Values(@data1, @data2)", connect); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `using` statement to dispose of resources. Your string split will produce an empty entry at the beginning, so try to use `StringSplitOptions`.

```
const string connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\xp\Desktop\HydroDatabase.accdb";
const string commandText = "INSERT Into HydroLog(WaterFlow,TurbineRPM) Values(@data1, @data2)";

string[] data = _serialPort.ReadExisting().Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

using(var connect = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
{
    using(var command = new OleDbCommand(commandText, connect))
    {
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@data1", data[0]);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@data2", data[1]);

        connect.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Romoku, thanks for the code. it run perfectly with no debug but it seems that the data been is not been record into the table. the data still send continuously.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this before it is executed.

```
command.Parameters.Add("@data1", OldeByType.VarChar).Value = data[0];
command.Parameters.Add("@data2", OldeByType.VarChar).Value = data[1];
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, how about the INSERT command is it correct?? the HYDROLOG will be the name of the table in access.